# FTC Robotics code is slow to start, becasue of "problem with "imu""

Tags: java, robotics

I am running some code for my FTC robotics team, but when I press init, an orange error appears: "problem with "imu"". There is no variable in our code named imu, and it is an orange runtime error, which is usually caused by a problem with the rev hub. After pressing run, there is a long delay before anything happens, after which the program runs as normal. What does this error mean?

Comment: Do you know what IMU stands for?

Comment: it appears to be some sort of sensor in the rev hub. Can you tell if it's a coding issue or a hardware issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using two rev hubs that are connect together check to make sure that in the I2C Bus 0 there is not two instances of IMU. Because the IMU is used for tasks like compass and gyro if you have two imu's in your configuration the app gets confused.